# How do I change a specific line of code in Debian

Tags: linux, windows, terminal, debian

I basically want to edit line 148 in gitian-builder/bin/gbuild of my Debian virtual machine. I am using bitvise to compile some stuff and I was wondering if there was a way to change that line from the bitvise terminal or by some other way?

I want to change the line from -
`author_date = cd inputs/#{dir} && TZ=UTC git log --date=format-local:%F %T --format="%ad" -1.strip` 
this to
`author_date = cd inputs/#{dir} && TZ=UTC git log --date=local --format="%ad" -1.strip`

in order to rectify a compiling error

thanks!

Comment: You mean like `sed '148 s/--date=format-local:%F[ ]%T/--date=local/' gitian-builder/bin/gbuild`? (add the `-i` option to edit the file in-place)

Comment: also, why did you add the [ ] between %F and %T?

Comment: sorry for commenting for a third time, turns out it was a simple typo I made over and over again. I am really sorry and thank you so much!

Comment: The `[...]` in a regular expression is a character list of characters to match. It also has the benefit of not needing to escape any of the characters within it. Generally you would use `'\ '` to escape the space or use `\s` for whitespace -- all are fine. The `[ ]` is POSIX so it is guaranteed available.

Comment: No problems, it should work just fine -- I verified it here before posting in the comment. Let me know if that is what you were looking for (which I was a bit unclear of), and I'm happy to write it up in an answer with an explanation.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin So, I just use sed -i '148 /s--date......' and it should work? Or do I have to enter the authordate = part as well?

Comment: Well, each `'.'` will match any single character -- so if your count is good, it will work. Farm more fragile than just providing the text to replace (easier to spot problems than to pinpoint an off-by-one error in `"..........."`)